# tkinter about the state of button when the code run

Tags: python, tkinter, button, state

How to disable the button when the process (daemon?) associated is running backend (to prevent abusively click) and become available when the process is finished, while during the process runing, the main gui is always active.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
import time


win = tk.Tk()

def test():
    time.sleep(3)

but1 = tk.Button(win, text="Run", command=test)
but1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: How can someone click in that button when process is daemon?

Comment: Try adding `but1.config(state="disabled")` to disable the button and `but1.config(styate="normal")` to re-enable the button. Also you shouldn't run anything that can take a long time (like `time.sleep(3)`) in the same thread as `tkinter`

Answer (score 0):

Create an if statement or while loop like such. Something like this that works for your use case.

```
if daemon:
  but1.config(state = 'disabled')
else:
 but1.config(state = 'normal')
```

Comment: Using while loops when using `tkinter` is a bad idea unless you really know what you are doing.